# Do we have to initialize class methods in Watir:Browser before using them?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to programming, trying to write some automated test code to test a website. I am able to open up a browser through code, but when I try to invoke any commands like 
@browser.image(:src => "img.gif").loaded? OR 
@browser.button(:id => "btn").enabled?

I get the error message - NoMethodError: undefined method `show_all_objects' for #

Should I initialize them before calling? and how? Big thanks for any help.

Comment: Try posting some code

Comment: require "watir"
require "watir-webdriver"
require 'watir-launcher'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Program Files (x86)\NW FF\firefox.exe'
@browser = WatirLauncher.launch_browser
@browser.goto("www.google.com")
puts @browser.text.include? 'Google'
@browser.show_all_objects()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to initialize any additional code. The problem is that you are calling:

```
@browser.show_all_objects()
```

The `show_all_objects` method does not exist. The method existed in the original Watir implementation, which is now called Watir-Classic. However, the method was [removed in Aug 2012](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/commit/701a44aeaa4bd4e03634da88104278da318cef3a). The method was never implemented in Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Thanks Justin. How do I get the list of current methods in Watir / Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: I usually start by checking the [RubyDoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/).

Comment: I bumped into that ruby doc earlier, but it is unclear to me on how to follow it. For example, under Image, there is loaded? function, how do I use it? I saw the View Source as well.

Comment: It would be called as you mentioned in the question - `@browser.image(:src => "img.gif").loaded?`

Comment: Thanks Justin, will do.

Comment: I still get the "Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element" error. I have Jruby and not Ruby..wonder would that matter?

Comment: `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException` means that Watir cannot find the element you are looking for. There are quite a few reasons that could be occurring. I have a page that [lists some of the frequent problems](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/). If that does not solve the problem, you will need to share HTML and Watir code that reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks Justin, it was inside a frame!